# Call proc without providing output parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, parameters

This runs:

```
declare @x int
exec spc_trace @spc='lets_wait', @session=@x out
```

Whereas this:

```
exec spc_trace @spc='lets_wait'
```

returns:

> Procedure or function 'spc_trace' expects parameter '@session', which
> was not supplied.

So, as long as an output parameter is defined, is it obligatory? Is there no way to get around this in cases the user simply doesn't need the output value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All proc parameters are input parameters. If a parameter is tagged as output then it is also an output parameter.
To make a parameter "optional" (whether output or not) , assign it a default value as usual.

```
create procedure testproc @in int = null, @out int = null output
as
begin
 select isnull(@in, 0) + isnull(@out, 0) as [in+out]
 select @out = 1000
end
go

exec testproc;
exec testproc @in = default, @out = default;
exec testproc @in = 10;
exec testproc @out = 20;

declare @x int = 100;
exec testproc @out = @x output;
select @x;

declare @y int = 100;
exec testproc @out = @y;
select @y;
```

Comment: Nice, I wasn't using the "=" in the `@out int = null output` part.